# Toolbar overlaps statusbar only for iPhone 4/4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, layout

I'm facing this annoying problem with my App layout.
As you can see from the image at following [link](https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AADvFPSsvLlHQrb1f58r8FGl6FOJng9DpoHPifaHjgW-Xw/12/333654050/jpeg/32x32/1/1439460000/0/2/Senzanome.gif/CKLQjJ8BIAEgAiADIAQgBSAGIAcoAg/6_fKTMrAeu32e64HrxeVip4an6R2j0Gb9Iqf-aGSxtY?size=1280x960&size_mode=2), toolbar is overlapping the statusbar only for iPhone 4/4s (next devices it works perfectly).
It's a 4 years old app, Objective-C written, I'm "inheriting" it from old dev team that never noticed this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using default navigation bar...

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle different the iPhone 4/4s screen using:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 1000
```

And do whatever is necessary for the specific device screen size. You can find all iPhone device resolutions [here](http://www.iphoneresolution.com)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok. It's quite similar to the solution that I was approciating but I have one more problem: in this project there are more than 400 .xib files, so I should implement this control to any of these. I'm looking for something generic.